# How to get metadata PDF file produced by Camscanner using laravel?

Tags: laravel, pdf, metadata

I have many PDF files that created from various app pdfcreator.I'm trying to extract PDF metadata that related with file created time in Laravel. I got failed when extracted from PDF file produced by CamScanner. Here is my code and file screenshot:

```
$path = "../temp/";
$files = File::allFiles($path);
dd($files)
?>
<table class="table">
<thead>
<th>FileName</th> <th>Created Time</th> <th>Modif Time</th>
</thead>

<tbody>
@foreach($files as $file)
<tr>
    <td>{{$file->getBasename()}}</td>
    <td>{{date("F d Y H:i:s.", $file->getCTime())}}</td>
    <td>{{date("F d Y H:i:s.", $file->getMTime())}}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
</tbody>
</table>
```

This is the original File that created with Camscanner

[image: PDF File produced by CamScanner]

Trying with `dd` function but get false result as shown below:

[image]

Thanks you

Comment: What's the error you're getting? What version of laravel are you using?

Comment: File Created Time is wrong .